# SVG Y position on second transformed element - makes no sense?

Tags: html, image, svg, image-processing

This isn't so much a problem as curious why the Y positioning is as is on second layout.

Both faces are isometric (using 30 and 60 degrees).

You would have thought I would have to calculate the second Y as 100 * (100 / tan(30)).

[image: isometric squares]

```html
<svg width="300" height="150" >
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" 
        transform="rotate(30, 0, 0) skewX(30) scale(1, 0.86062)" 
        style="fill:none;stroke:#FF0000;"></rect>
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" 
        transform="rotate(-30, 0, 0) skewX(-30) scale(1, 0.86062)" 
        style="fill:none;stroke:#00FF00;"></rect>
</svg>
```

Why on earth does it need to be y="100" on green square in second example?

I tried grouping and changing the order of display, makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The origin of the green square is still at (0, 0), because this is the default value of the [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform-origin) property. This means that all transforms are relative to (0, 0):

```html
<svg width="300" height="200" fill="none">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" stroke="red"
        transform="rotate(30 0 0) skewX(30) scale(1 .86062)"/>
  <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" stroke="#0F0"
        transform="rotate(-30 0 0) skewX(-30) scale(1 .86062)"/>

  <!-- notice the position of the top left corner of the green rectangle -->
  <rect x="0" y="100" width="200" height="100" stroke="none" fill="#0F03"
        transform="rotate(-30 0 0) skewX(-30) scale(1 .86062)"/>
</svg>
```

If you find that unintuitive you can place the square at (0, 0) and use `translate()` to position it afterwards. You can also simplify this a bit by using `skewY()` instead of `skewX()` + `rotate()` and flip the `scale()` arguments:

```html
<svg width="300" height="150" fill="none">
  <rect width="100" height="100" stroke="red"
        transform="skewY(30) scale(.86062 1)"/>
  <!-- (0 0) + translate() -->
  <rect width="100" height="100" stroke="#0F0"
        transform="translate(86.062 50) skewY(-30) scale(.86062 1)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm also going to have a read of
https://css-tricks.com/transforms-on-svg-elements/